# Get-DnsServerResourceRecord not working on 2016 server

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-server-2016

I have a powershell that utilizes the function Get-DnsServerResourceRecord.  I have it working on a couple of different servers for testing, but on the server that I want it to run from I get this error:

> Get-DnsServerResourceRecord : The term 'Get-DnsServerResourceRecord'
>   is not recognized as the name  of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a  path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:2
>   char:3
>   +         Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -ZoneNam ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DnsServerResourceRecord:String) [], CommandNotF     oundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

All of my googling has told me that since I am running this on a Windows Server 2016 (DataCenter) that this should just work.  What am I missing in order for this to run?

---

How I am actually running it:

```
$DNSServer = "dnsservername"
        $dnsrecord = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -ZoneName 'db.local' -RRType CName | Where-Object {$_.RecordData.HostNameAlias -like "*" -and $_.HostName -like "*.*"}  

        $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        [void]$Datatable.Columns.Add("CName")
        [void]$Datatable.Columns.Add("HostNameAlias")

        Foreach ($record in $dnsrecord)
        {
            [void]$Datatable.Rows.Add($record.HostName, $record.RecordData.HostNameAlias)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

(As of 2022)
List Installed Windows Features on Win10 (Powershell)

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where Name -Match "RSAT.*" | Format-Table -Autosize
```

Install RSAT.DNS.TOOLS

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.Dns.Tools
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install DNS server Tools module.
run below powershell command
Install-WindowsFeature rsat-dns-server

Comment: Install-WindowsFeature is not recognized either